# How is setInterval Interval managed?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

If I use the setInterval function to call an asynchronous JavaScript function each X seconds will the interval wait X seconds after the previous execution is finished or X seconds after the previous execution is called? E.g. if I display a timeline of the calls is it:

0 sec : setInterval(funcX, 10000)
10 sec : funcX - takes 3 seconds to execute
20 sec : funcX

or

0 sec : setInterval(funcX, 10000)
10 sec : funcX - takes 3 seconds to execute
23 sec : funcX

Comment: What the heck is your function doing that it takes 3 seconds to execute?

Comment: It's a AJAX call which is kicking off a series of ping commands against a list of servers - depending on the number of servers I'm hitting this could vary from 0.5s to 6-7s. I don't therefore want it kicking off the next series of commands less than 10 seconds after I get the previous response back

Comment: An AJAX call inside a function won't stop a function from completing. The function you are scheduling using `setInterval` completes nearly instantly, although any AJAX calls inside it may take longer.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call to that function.

Therefore it's every X seconds. But if the function takes longer than X seconds to execute, then the thread will be locked and will execute when it's free.

For more information on [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) timings I recommend John Resig's article *[How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)*.

---

If you wish for it to be X seconds after the function has executed, use `setTimeout()` and call this at the end of your function:

```
runFunc();

function runFunc(){
   //code here....
   setTimeout(runFunc, 3000);
}
```

This will cause infinite recursion, emulating `setInterval()`, but only starting the X second delay once the current function has finished executing.

Comment: `How long each function takes to execute is irrelevant.` <- That isn't strictly true.

Comment: @Asad You're correct, I wasn't taking into account functions running for that long! I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the function actually takes 3 seconds to execute, you have serious problems.

This is not particularly relevant to you because you are using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and the actual Ajax call should be practically instantaneous.

If you want the Ajax call to complete *before* the interval continues again, `setInterval` is undesirable.  Use `setTimeout` instead.

```
function atTime() {
    ajax().done(function () { setTimeout(atTime, 10000); });
}
atTime();
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The internal timer isn't implemented in JS, so it isn't locked up. The function would still execute at 20s, not 23s.

Comment: @Asad you even say that the internal timer would be locked up *in your own answer*

Comment: No I didn't. I'm saying that the thread for *function execution* would be locked up. The timer progresses fine. As long as there isn't a function executing at the point in time when setInterval tries to invoke the callback again, everything goes off without a hitch, as explained in my answer. In this specific case, since the execution duration is 3s, every invocation completes *before* the time when the next one is scheduled, so the second one would occur at 20s, not 23s.

Comment: @Asad your answer is confusing, but it's also irrelevant to the actual problem.  I removed my problematic statement.

Comment: My answer isn't really confusing or irrelevant. The question is: if a function takes X seconds to execute, and is scheduled to execute every Y seconds, does the function execute at Y, 2Y, 3Y, 4Y ... or at Y, 2Y+X, 3Y+2X ... Your answer claimed the latter (2(10) +3), which is wrong. My answer claims the former, which is correct, and answers the question.

Comment: In fact, mentioning AJAX is entirely irrelevant to the question (which doesn't mention it at all). You are addressing a comment in your answer.

Comment: You can't just edit the question to fit your answer. It makes the other answers irrelevant, even though they answer the actual question asked.

Comment: @Asad it's not to fit my answer, it's to correct the question.  The OP doesn't actually care about when the `setInterval` function will execute; they are trying to solve a specific problem

Comment: I don't feel that is a valid edit, but I've [brought this up for discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168484/is-it-acceptable-to-edit-a-question-to-fit-an-ops-comment).